# How do I mock next router in this custom hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, router, next.js

I have a custom hook that is used in a number of places, it intercepts a back action and calls the function that is passed in. I'm looking to verify that the correct function is called inside beforePopState. How would i go about mocking this?

```
const useBackNavigationIntercept = (action) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    router.beforePopState(() => {
      action();

      return false;
    });
  }, [action, router]);
};
```

I have a test where I'm trying to mock the router so that there is a specific value in the route and when the hook is called that the appropriate intercept action is called.

e.g. Testing a component that uses the hook:

```
import actions from '../../actions'

const SomeComponent = () => {
  ...
  const router = useRouter();
  const { country } = router.query;

  useBackNavigationIntercept(() => actions.someFunction(country));
  ...
}
```

And want to verify that `someFunction` is called with `UK` as an argument.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

**Update:**

`someFunction` is mocked as follows:

```
import actions from '../../actions';
jest.mock('../../actions');
jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
  useRouter: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    query: {
      country: 'UK',
    },
    beforePopState: require.requireActual('next/router'),
  })),
}));
...

// I'm expecting to be able to do something like this

it('calls someFunction with the correct args', () => {
  render(<SomeComponent {...props} />
  history.back();
  expect(actions.someFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith('UK')
});
```

Comment: Where `someFunction` comes from?

Comment: `someFunction` could be anything, e.g. I could have defined a `logout` function elsewhere and am calling it inside the hook's callback

Comment: You are testing a specific Component, it uses your custom hook, where does this component gets someFunction from?

Comment: I have a defined list of reusable actions in another file. I'm just mocking it inside the test (updated to reflect this)

Comment: Where does `SomeComponent` gets the `someFunction` function? is it hard coded there? is it gets by import?

Comment: It imports it, i've updated to reflect this

Comment: these props that are get spread on SomeComponent has `actions.someFunction`?

Comment: It shouldn't need them, because the actions are imported and then mocked in the test

Comment: Ha, sorry, now I see what I need :] writing a proper answer

Answer (score 2):

login.spec.tsx

```
    import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
    
    jest.mock('next/router', () => {
      const router = {
        push: jest.fn(),
        pathname: '/',
        route: '',
        asPath: '',
        query: {},
        events: {
          on: jest.fn(),
          off: jest.fn(),
          emit: jest.fn(),
        },
      };
      return {
        useRouter: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(router),
      };
    });


    it('should save userData on cookie when user submit the form', async () => {
        mockedGetAuth.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve(fakeResponseData))
        renderTemplate()
    
        const username = '19105'
        const password = '123456'
    
        const usernameInput = screen.getByLabelText('Login')
        const passwordInput = screen.getByLabelText('Senha')
    
        await userEvent.type(usernameInput, username)
    
        await userEvent.type(passwordInput, password)
    
        const button = screen.getByRole('button', { name: /entrar/i })
    
        await userEvent.click(button)
    
        document.cookie = `userData=${JSON.stringify(fakeResponseData)}`
    
        expect(document.cookie).toBe(`userData=${JSON.stringify(fakeResponseData)}`)
    
        expect(useRouter().push).toBeCalledWith('/')
      })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to mock the import of `../actions` and provide a spy method to it.

The tricky part is the **import order** of files in the test, cause you want to mock the import **before** your component code imports it...

it should look like:

```js
// SomeComponent.spec.jsx
const actionsMock = {
  someFunction: jest.fn()
};

jest.mock('../../actions', () => actionsMock);
jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
  useRouter: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    query: {
      country: 'UK',
    },
    beforePopState: jest.requireActual('next/router'),
  })),
}));

const SomeComponent = require('../path-to/SomeComponent')
// --------------------^ it should be required and not imported 
// because "import" must be the first thing in the file, and we have our mock definition

it('calls someFunction with the correct args', () => {
  render(<SomeComponent {...props} />;
  history.back();
  expect(actionsMock.someFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith('UK');
});
```